# Visibility in C

Tags: c

If I have a function:

```
void G(int f){

    printf("Hello");

}
```

(I know that this function doesn't make sense to have the parameter, but I have it just for the sake of the question)

Would "int f" be visible inside the function even though it has no definition and is not used within it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "visible" here?

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of function parameters?

Comment: The variable named `f` is in scope inside the function `G`. You can use it like you would any other local variable you might declare inside the function.

Comment: The answer is too short to put in answer box - *Yes*.

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound? Your question is exactly this. Is `f` visible if no one is using it? By the way `f` has a definition, namely `int f`.

Comment: Is there a pressure transducer located anywhere within a "pressure-measurement-limit" radius of the falling tree? For the questions' tree, add `printf ("Hello: %p", (void*)&f);` and find out.

Comment: What is the sound of one hand clapping? Why, it's "whoosh" of course. Damned philosophers and their stupid questions :-)

Comment: Read about the as-if rule. The C compiler is allowed to remove the tree and the sound if no one is witnessing that. You wouldn't know.

Comment: Yeah, off topic here,  you need to find a philosophy site.

Comment: It's kinda like 'int myFunction(){return 1};' with 'myFunction()'.  Where does the returned value go?

Comment: `void G(int f){ ...` is a function definition.

Answer (score 5):

> even though it has no definition

is not quite right. It actually *does* have a definition, it's right there in the function declaration. Whether or not you *use* it is a totally different matter.

Be that as it may, the term you're using, visibility, is okay for beginners but the language specification (and the language lawyers like myself that use it) prefer the term scope.

And the scope of variables is covered in (for C11) `6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers`. Stanza `/4` of that section states (my emphasis):

> If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block ***or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block.***

That means the variable is "visible" all the way to the end of the function block (assuming you don't shadow it by introducing another variable of the same name in an inner scope).

Answer (score 1):

> Would "int f" be visible inside the function even though it has no definition and is not used within it?

By your logic `int f` would be visible if it would be used, **but** it can only be used if it is visible before it is used...

In short, the visibility is not connected to the fact the variable isn't used. It is visible since it was sent as an argument.